# How to make bool value false on cross button click?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm building a login form in which i have a bool value which becomes true when user click on login button from login page .Now i want that if user clicks on cross button to close the MDI form that bool value should become false and user is able to login again from login form.How can i do that?
In my case i'm unable to do that when i click on cross button it shows error message "You are already logged in" but if form is closed it should allow me to login again.
please help me get out of this.

```
Here is the code for the login form----

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Login
{
    public partial class LogIin : Form
    {
        public bool IsLoggedIn { get; set; }


        public LogIin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=IBMPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=UserData;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from User_Credential where UserName = @UserName and Passwords = @Passwords", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UsTxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passwords", PassTxt.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            con.Open();
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            {

                if (!IsLoggedIn)
                {

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {

                        Welcome_Form wf = new Welcome_Form();

                        wf.Show();
                        IsLoggedIn = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter Correct Username and Password");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You are already logged in", "Error");
                }

            }
        }


        private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your buttons event handler.

```
IsLoggedIn = false;
```

Or

```
IsLoggedIn = true;
```

Create an additional column in the database (for example IsLoggedIn), and save the value into it when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you close the window you have to set the value to false.

```
 private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsLoggedIn = false;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the bool value false when user clicks on the cross button of the Welcome_Form, make the IsLoggedIn public static in LogIin:

```
// In LogIin form:
 public static bool IsLoggedIn;
```

And set the value false from the FormClosing event of the Welcome_Form:

```
private void Form_WelCome_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
 LogIin.IsLoggedIn = false;
}
```

Comment: I have done that actually i have different form when user clicks on login button another welcome from displays. How can i set value to false in that form?

Comment: Is the IsLoggedIn declared in the login form, and you want to set it false from the welcome form?

Comment: Yes it is in the login form

Comment: Then, make the IsLoggedIn public static in Login form:

        // In FormLogin:
        public static bool IsLoggedIn;

And set the value to false from the FormClosing event of the welcome form:

private void FormWelCome_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            FormLogin.IsLoggedIn = false;
        }

Comment: Thank you so much it works please tell me one more thing why cant i use non static field for doing so?

Comment: You are welcome, Non static fields are only accessible from the instance of the form. Here, we are setting the value of the LogIin form without creating instance of the form, so using static. Please don't forget to give an up-vote as you find the answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have created IsLoggedIn variable as local variable, we can't use local variable to identity user is log in or not.

You will have to use global variable for it.

You can do by using static class. like this:

```
static class Global
{
private static Bool IsLoggedIn;

public static Bool IsLoggedIn
{
    get { return IsLoggedIn; }
    set { IsLoggedIn= value; }
}
}
```

and for using any where you can write:

```
GlobalClass.IsLoggedIn=true;
```

I hope it work for you :)